# How to add NS Operation QOS = .UserInteractive to query function

Tags: swift, uitableview, cloudkit, nsoperationqueue

I've been browsing numerous forums and tutorials in the hopes of speeding up my cloudkit app - (at the very least) it seems that the answer comes down to setting the quality of service function to "UserInteractive".  At the moment, it takes about 2/3 seconds to update a table controller with 3 records, each with only a string variable, displayed through a label.  To my knowledge, setting the qos to be user interactive will force the UI to update faster.  However, I am unsure how to properly implement the qos code in its entirety.  As it stands, here is my code that takes 2/3 seconds to load.

```
  func fetch()
    {   
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dining", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
        else
        {
            for result in results!
            {    
              self.categories.append(result)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in         
              self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        }
}
     fetch()   
}
```

therefore, to acheive a quicker UI response, would I be able to implement something like this?

```
 func fetch()
    {   
    let publicDatabase =     CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dining", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
        else
        {
            for result in results!
            {    
              self.categories.append(result)
            }

            let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_UserInteractive
    let Queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(Queue, {
    print("This is run on the background queue")

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
   self.tableView.reloadData()
})
})

        }
        }
}
     fetch()   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a query operation along these lines:

```
func fetch(){
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dining", predicate: predicate)
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {(record: CKRecord) -> Void in
        // Do things with record
    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor, error) in
        // Handle error and do things

        }
     }
publicDB.add(queryOperation)
}
```

See documentation on NSOperation and its instance property QualityofService